# data analysis 4 participant groups from questionnaire data

Tags: survey, group-differences

all of my data is being collected from an online questionnaire. two of the questions will act as independent variables and will allow me to sort the respondents into groups for analysis. I will have 4 groups to compare during analysis (group 1: yes to Q1&Q2; group 2: yes to Q1, no to Q2; group 3: no to Q1&Q2; group 4: no to Q1, yes to Q2). 
in spss I will create one column for Q1 and another column for Q2. each column will have 2 values: 1 for yes, 2 for no. 
I have worked out how to compare all 4 groups but I don't know how to compare just two groups. I want to compare group 1 (yes to Q1&Q2) and group (no to Q1, yes to Q2).

Comment: If you want to know how to implement this in SPSS you would be better on an SPSS site. Do you have a statistical question about how to compare them? If so we need more details about what you are comparing them on.

Comment: I've got lots of dependent variables in my study. half the DVs will be compared for all 4 groups. the other half will only be compared between the 2 groups that I said. I am just not sure about how to isolate the data for the 2 groups so that I can compare them on the second half of the DVs